# g-sorted-ness is not affected by later h-sorting : is proof correct?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, proof

**Hypothesis** : An array A is g-sorted. I.e. for all integers x and a specific integer g, *A[x] < A[x+g] < A[x+2g] ...*

Now, if we h sort after copying it into array B, to achieve the condition : for another specific integer h, *B[x] < B[x+h] < B[x+2h] ...*

The hypothesis is that after h-sorting it, the array still remains g-sorted for arbitrary integers h and g.

**Proof**: If contrary to the hypothesis, h-sorting will affect g-sorted-ness, it will be due to A[x1] > A[x1+h], for some x1 in the g-sorted array A, and we swapped the elements at x and x+h - and this swapping ends up destroying g-sortedness

Now, we know that for all x,  A[x-g] < A[x] < A[x+g] < A[x+2g] since it is already g-sorted.

So, A[x+h-g] < A[x+h] < A[x+h+g]

For a specific x=x1, we have A[x1] > A[x1+h] so we need to swap elements at x1, and x1+h. Before swapping, the condition of the array is : for all x

{A[x-g] ; A[x+h-g]} < A[x+h] < A[x] < {A[x+g] ; A[x+h-g]}

Where the {} notation means that we don't know the order of elements within {}, but each element within {} separately satisfies the sortedness condition.

For a specific x=x1, even if we swap elements at x1+h and x1, the condition before swap is

{A[x1-g] ; A[x1+h-g]} < **A[x1+h] < A[x1]** < {A[x1+g] ; A[x1+h-g]}

After swap, it is

GOLD : {B[x1-g] ; B[x1+h-g]} < **B[x1] < B[x1+h]** < {B[x1+g] ; B[x1+h-g]}

This could destroy g-sorted-ness in 2 ways :
1. B[x1] > B[x1-g]
2. B[x1+g] > B[x1]

But the above after swap condition marked GOLD shows, both of these destroy conditions are not true. Hence after h-sorting a g-sorted array, g-sorted-ness is not destroyed.

**Question** : Is this a mathematically valid proof? Please comment.

Answer (score -1):

The proof is no good because the hypothesis is false. Consider the following h-sorting algorithm:

1. Dump the contents of the g-sorted array on the floor.
2. Shuffle the elements around a little while and go have lunch.
3. Come back and h-sort the elements.

This results in an array of elements that is h-sorted but no longer g-sorted. Well we really should show that there are ways of h-sorting that aren't g-sorted for the above argument to work. The example is trivial. Let g = 1 and h = 2. Take the array

```
A = 1 2 3 4
```

A is g-sorted and h-sorted. But the following arrangement of the elements if h-sorted but not g-sorted:

```
B = 1 3 2 4
```

Therefore h-sorting is not guaranteed to result in a g-sorted list.

Now there are things called *stable* sorting algorithms; by definition, an h-sorting algorithm would be g-stable if it preserved the property you are trying to show holds. You would need to prove the g-stable property for a particular h-sorting algorithm, though, and it would apply to that algorithm, not h-sorting generally.

Comment: 1. Dump the contents of the g-sorted array on the floor.
  `<OK>`

2. Shuffle the elements around a little while and go have lunch.
   `<Does this mean it is no more g-sorted ?>`

3. Come back and h-sort the elements.
    `<OK>`

This results in an array of elements that is h-sorted but no longer g-sorted. `<OK - but that was never the hypothesis>`
<br/>
Hypothesis is that a g-sorted array, when h-sorted, preserves its g-sortedness. You inserted an extra step of scrambling the array between taking a g-sorted array and h-sorting it.

Comment: @Jeeves That's a step in my h-sorting algorithm: first shuffle everything around (pseudo-)randomly, and then perform some other h-sorting algorithm. My algorithm is the following: perform some action which in general cannot be proved to preserve the g-sortedness of the original array; then, h-sort the array. This is an algorithm and by construction cannot be proved to preserve g-sortedness. It does not prove you will never end up with a g-sorted array. Randomness/arbitrariness is useful here since I now only have to show a single example of it failing to produce a g-sorted array for any input.

Comment: The whole point is that when you are h-sorting the array, at that precise point, the array should already be g-sorted. Then, and only then, the hypothesis is that h-sorting will preserve g-sortedness. No one is saying that for arbitrary values of h and g, h-sorting "causes" g-sorting.

Comment: @Jeeves I think there is a misunderstanding. If you are trying to prove that it is possible to h-sort a g-sorted array so as to maintain g-sortedness, it is possible. If you are trying to prove that h-sorting a g-sorted array must necessarily result in a g-sorted array, that is what I'm pointing out is wrong. It seems like you're saying that if h-sort a g-sorted array, for arbitrary h and g, you maintain g-sortedness, which is not true. Is that what you are saying? Or are you proving it's possible to h-sort a g-sorted array while maintaining g-sortedness?

Comment: Hypothesis : The process of h-sorting a g-sorted array, by itself, does not cause it to lose g-sortedness. So any step that takes a g-sorted array closer to h-sortedness does not make it lose g-sortedness.

Comment: @Jeeves You should update your question to include this extra condition. In general, an algorithm for X does not need to get closer to X at every step. It just has to end up there. Plenty of h-sorting algorithms will go out of their way to get there. You may have difficulty formalizing the notion of "closer" but maybe something in terms of minimum number of required swaps would work. Not all h-sorting algorithms have the property you are assuming in the question but stating in the a above comment.